# Multiple ASP Identity in same project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have MVC5 project with front end and back end. Both have login, however they are in the same project. Is it possible to use 2 ASP Identity in one project because I need to separate them (for example if a user login in backend, he will still need to login on frontend).

How to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Are them (front end and back end ) both server side projets?

Comment: Yes, both sit under one MVC5 project but separate database

Comment: So What is the problem? Two separated projects will be hosted in two separated virtual dirs and there's noway to use a same Identity for both of them. What you may need is to set them to use two different databases to separate concerns.

Comment: It has different `Users` database, but it's sitting under same project. For example, I login on frontend as "warheat1990", when I go to backend page and call `User.IsAuthenticated`, it will return true because I already logged in on frontend. Basically I want to separate them without using Claims/Role.